# Linq Greater and Less Than operator on string containing date

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing a linq query in my application that I want to use a "less than" operator on.  However column I am trying to apply it to is of type string (which we can't change) and is causing intellisense to throw an error as the "<" operator cannot be used on string type.

My question is how else can I do this?  Here is the part of my code that the error occurs on.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<VesselViewModel>>(db.tbl_vessels
    .Where(p => 
          (p.vessel_type.Contains("AHTS")) &&
          (p.spotlist_id == 2) &&
          (p.fixture_start <= System.DateTime.Now.Date)
     )
    .ToList());
    return View(results);
}
```

`fixture_start` is a string, we can't change it due to complications elsewhere. Is there anyway around this problem?

Comment: It might help if you post the entire piece of LINQ code. It's hard to tell what's wrong with such a small snippet.

Comment: `(DateTime.Parse(p.fixture_start) <= System.DateTime.Now.Date)`

Comment: Assuming it's because `p.fixture_start` is a string and therefore cannot be less than anything. Convert it to a DateTime.

Comment: Please be aware the this `LINQ` is executed against a `SQL-Server` `DateTime.Parse` would not work, because it cannot be translated into `SQL`

Comment: I've posted the full statement Gilgamesh, I can't change the datatype Equalsk it causes problems through the rest of the application.  Michael is correct if you look at my response below, parsing isn't allowed as it can't be translated.

Comment: Wondering when the people will stop storing numeric/datetime data as string.

Comment: Typically I wouldn't Ivan but again this isn't by choice.  This is not my database I'm working with.  I am writing the backend for the application to talk to it.

Answer (score 4):

If `p.fixture_start` is a string containing a date, then you will have to parse it before compare:

```
(p => DateTime.Parse(p.fixture_start) <= System.DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you can't change the type of fixture_start ,you could parse it to DateTime, just for the query:

```
(DateTime.Parse(p.fixture_start) <= System.DateTime.Now.Date)
```

Isn't that an option?

Comment: This approach gives the following error:

{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: I see, your first example code doesn't show the whole problem - we can't use method calls within a LINQ Query thats right

Answer (score 0):

Well, a solution could be executing part of your query using [Linq to Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb386964(v=vs.110).aspx) and end your query using [Linq to Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) where you can convert an `string` to `DateTime`:

```
var results = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<VesselViewModel>>(db.tbl_vessels
             .Where(p => 
                   (p.vessel_type.Contains("AHTS")) &&
                   (p.spotlist_id == 2))
             .AsEnumerable()// This should make the trick
             .Where(p => DateTime.Parse(p.fixture_start) <= System.DateTime.Now.Date)
             .ToList());
```

Comment: Thanks for this octavioccl, this approach gives an error of: Unable to create a constant value of type "'MyProject.Models.tbl_vessels'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: I don't see nothing that throw that Exception. Do you have any other condition where you compare an instance of `tbl_vessels`?

Answer (score 0):

If fixture_date is a string. You should be comparing it to a string. If this is a date stored as a string in your database, it should be stored as yyyymmdd. If this is the case then you can compare it with the current date formatted in the same way. You will be able to use less than to compare two strings.

```
p.fixture_date <= System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMd") // not sure this format is correct
```